# Socket.io event emitting multiple times

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am creating a chat app with real-time notifications, the notifications get sent, but they get sent a random number of times when they should get sent just once. I am using react on the frontend and node.js on the backend.

Here are my socket events:

```
socket.on('sendNotification', function(recipientId, notification) {
        console.log('send notification is firing');
      //find the room where the title is the recipient
      Room.findOne({'title':  recipientId}, function(err, room){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('this is the notification room found', room.id);
        socket.broadcast.to(room.id).emit('addNotification', notification);
      });
       socket.join(theRoom.id);
    });
```

//    // //thiss should be on the client

```
   socket.on('joinYourNotificationRoom', function(userId){
    Room.findOne({'title' :userId}, function(err, room){
        if(err) throw 'thisd is the error to join your notifiaction room' + err;
        if(room){
          console.log('about to join a your notification room ');
        socket.join(room.id);
      }else{
        Room.create({
          title: userId
        }, function(err, newRoom, socket){
         socket.join(newRoom.id);
         console.log('new notifaction room created');
       });
     };
   });
});
```

Here is where I send the notifications after sending the messages on the frontend:

```
console.log('these are the users in the application', this.state.users);
let theUsers = [].concat.apply([], this.state.users);
console.log('theUsers', theUsers);

for(let user of theUsers){
  console.log('this is one of the users', user);
  if(user._id !== this.props.auth.user.id){
    let notification = {};
    let notificationText = user.name + " sent a message in room " + this.props.currentRoom.title;
    notification.recipient = user._id;
    notification.text = notificationText;
    console.log('join notification about to be submitted', user._id);
    this.state.socket.emit('sendNotification', user._id, notification);
  }
}
```

Here is my notification room on the frontend:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import {notificationToServer, getNotifications} from 
 '../../actions';
import NotificationContainer from './NotificationContainer';
import axios from 'axios';

const socketURL="http://localhost:3000";
class Notifications extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      notifications:[],
      socket:null
    }
    this.initSocket();
  }

  initSocket = () =>{
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:5002', {
    transports: ['websocket'], jsonp: false });
    socket.connect();
    socket.on('connect', ()=>{
      this.setState({socket: socket});
      this.state.socket.emit('joinYourNotificationRoom', user.id);
      this.state.socket.on('addNotification', (notification)=>{
        this.props.notificationToServer(notification, ()=> {
          console.log('callback fired');
          //clear notifications
          this.props.getNotifications(user.id);
        });
      });
    })
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    this.props.getNotifications(user.id);
  }


  render() {
    console.log('these are the notifications', this.props.notification);
    let notifications = this.props.notifications.map((notification)=>
      <NotificationContainer notification={notification} />

    );
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h6>Notifications</h6>
        {notifications}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return{
    auth:state.auth,
    notifications: state.notifications.notifications
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps,
```

{ getNotifications, notificationToServer})(Notifications);

Answer (score 0):

This should be due to creating multiple connections with the server and subscribing the same event multiple times. In your case the `initSocket` method could be called multiple time. Try `console.log` inside the `initSocket` method and make sure it is only called one time since it is possible to create multiple `Notification` components.

If so move your socket connection logic to a separate file (ES6 Module) and communicate through that.

Comment: I console.logged initSocket and it printed only once